# Assigning lower case alphabet as keys in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, set, python-3.4

I'm working on a simple little piece of code that takes a text file, and assigns keys in the dict as each letter in the english alphabet a-z, and each word that starts with that letter is assigned to the key as a set.  I know there must be a more "pythonic" way of doing this?

```
# P8.11 : This program builds a dictionary of sets from a text file of words.
# The keys are a letter, and the values are a set of words that start with that
# letter.

def main():
    wordList = set()
    inFile = open("words.txt", "r")
    for line in inFile:
        line = line.rstrip()
        line = line.lower()
        wordList = line.split()
        print(buildDict(wordList))
    print(wordList)
def buildDict(wordList):
    wordDict = dict()
    for word in wordList:
        if word.startswith("a"):
            wordDict["a"] = word
        if word.startswith("b"):
            wordDict["b"] = word
        if word.startswith("c"):
            wordDict["c"] = word
        if word.startswith("d"):
            wordDict["d"] = word
        if word.startswith("e"):
            wordDict["e"] = word
        if word.startswith("f"):
            wordDict["f"] = word
        if word.startswith("g"):
            wordDict["g"] = word
        if word.startswith("h"):
            wordDict["h"] = word
        if word.startswith("i"):
            wordDict["i"] = word

    return wordDict
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want to extract the first letter from `word`, and use it as the key. `setdefault` ensures that if `word_dict[word[0]]` doesn't exist yet, it is added as a key.

```
for word in word_list:
    word_dict.setdefault(word[0], set()).add(word)
```

You can also use a `defaultdict`.

```
import collections

word_dict = collections.defaultdict(set)
for word in word_list:
    word_dict[word[0]].add(set0)
```

Finally, a one-liner using the `itertools` and `operator` modules (split in to multiple lines for readability). `groupby` takes care of grouping the words by their first letter; `itemgetter` is just another way of writing `lambda x: x[0]`)

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

word_dict = dict((letter, set(words)) 
                 for letter, words in groupby(sorted(word_list), 
                                              key=itemgetter(0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

There's definitely a more Pythonic way:

```
from collections import defaultdict

word_dict = defaultdict(set)

with open('words.txt') as f:
     for word in f:
         word_dict[word[0]].add(word)

print(word_dict)
```

Comment: +1 for great refactor - you may want to guard again zero length words though. :)

Comment: @MariaZverina That's a great idea, but I think it's probably OK to assume correct input in order to keep the answer concise and relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the first character of the word instead of startswith.

```
from collections import defaultdict   
def buildDict(wordList):
     wordDict=defaulttict(set)
     for word in wordList:
          wordDict[word[0]].add(word)
```

Comment: This is the same thing I posted in my answer.

Comment: I started the answer as there wasn't any answers around